# how to display 3 items at each slide when pulling the data from db and not via static html?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I was looking at the docs of this slider document

```
http://www.slidesjs.com/#docs
```

and i can't seem to find how to display 3 items at a slide e.g if I have
a $data object and did a php foreach loop like e.g

```
foreach($data as $item){

//echo out ul li to display image of the data

}
```

but if i do that, it only displays the 1 item at a slide..in a static html version..
there are  3 batch of `ul li` that displays  3 images at each slide e.g

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

if am gonna include 3 batch of ul and li inside the foreach loop, it'll just produce redundant data

Comment: Try [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/examples/display-move-multiple-slides-once-example-one)

Comment: what exactly you want could you add

Comment: not sure i understand what you are after, if you want to have a single UL and 3 LI within it then just put the UL outside the foreach loop and just the <li>$item</li> in the loop

Comment: putting the UL outside the foreach loop didn't help ...how can you because the foreach($data as $item){} ..the $item is an object ....if am gonna put it in a single <li> ..it will just print one <li> ...if am gonna put it within 3 <li> , it will produce 3 <li> with the "SAME" content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work fine

```
foreach($data as $item){
   echo"<ul>
     <li>{$item}</li>
   </ul>";

}
```